# Is it possible to control loop(forEach) on click of button on JSP page?

Tags: spring-boot, jsp

I'm trying to create a question/answer quiz where there are multiple choice answers(in radio buttons) per question.
I want to display One question and it's relevant set of answers at a time. How do I iterate over the list with control so on click it would display the next question and answers?

```
    <form action="/addStuResponse" method="post">       
        
        <c:forEach items="${qlist}" var="question"  varStatus="loopCounter">    
        
            <input type="hidden" name="quesSet" value="${question.quesId}">     
            <textarea rows="3" cols="5" readonly="readonly">${question.quesText}</textarea>
            
            <c:forEach items="${anslist}" var="answer">
                <c:if test="${answer.questions.quesId == question.quesId}">
                    
                    <input type="radio" name="response" value="${answer.answer}">                           
                
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:forEach>
        
            <button type="submit" >Next</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: you can  add some hidden inputs where you can store value of `next` question id inside form .So on submit you can get that value using `${param.yourqid}` and pass that in your loop and show only that question

Comment: I'm really sorry but I'm not getting it.

Comment: You need to submit your form on every question ?

Comment: Yes I do, that means hitting controller  number(length question list) of times.

Comment: So you can just show first question inside `form` and add one `hiddeninput` field which will have `id` of  next question to be display so on submit you can get the hidden input value and pass the same to your loop and display only the required question.Do the same until you reach last question.This is one way to do and other way is shown in @Pradyskumar answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a flag `isCurrentQuestion`on each question. Set first question flag to `true` and rest of the questions flag to `false`. Onclick of next button change the isCurrentQuestion flag to false for first question and make the second question as true. and continue like this until the last question.

Modify your code as below:

```
 <form action="/addStuResponse" method="post">       
        
        <c:forEach items="${qlist}" var="question"  varStatus="loopCounter">    
          <c:if test="${question.isCurrentQuestion == true}">
            <input type="hidden" name="quesSet" value="${question.quesId}">     
            <textarea rows="3" cols="5" readonly="readonly">${question.quesText}</textarea>
            
            <c:forEach items="${anslist}" var="answer">
                <c:if test="${answer.questions.quesId == question.quesId}">
                    
                    <input type="radio" name="response" value="${answer.answer}">                           
                
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach>
          </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
        
            <button type="submit" >Next</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: This was painful ... very.